# AutoLISP: How to solve no function definition error?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, autocad, autolisp

Below I have pasted the code from my `drawmycoil.lsp` file.

```
(defun drwcoil ()
  (setq helices_center '(0 0)) ; this is the center of the helices
  (setq inner_radius 1e3)      ; 1000 microns
  (setq outer_radius 2.4e3)    ; 2400 microns
  (setq coil_thickness 35)     ; 35 microns
  (setq turns (\ (- outer_radius inner_radius)
                 (* coil_thickness 2))) ; coil_thickness is multiplied by 2 to
                                        ; account for coil spacing
  (while (< inner_radius outer_radius)
    (command "HELIX"
             helices_center
             inner_radius
             (+ inner_radius (* coil_thickness 2))
             "t"
             "1"
             "0") ;draws one helix per iteration
    (setq inner_radius 
          (+ inner_radius (* coil_thickness 2))))) ; increments the inner radius
                                                   ; for the next iteration

(defun c:drawmycoil ()
  (drwcoil)
  (princ))
```

Here's the output of the lisp file after it is loaded and executed:

```
Command: _appload coil35um_intricate.lsp successfully loaded. 

Command: 

Command:  

Command: drawmycoil  ; 
error: no function definition: \\\\
```

In spite of having clearly defined my functions, I am unable to make AutoCAD/AutoLISP recognize them. I am using Autodesk Education Master Suite 2011. I saw quite a few tutorial sites and most of them are focused on the LISP part of the functions. I am more focused on making AutoCAD plot my drawing for me through LISP.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this code from your post:

```
(setq turns (\ (-
```

I suspect you meant to use `/` instead of `\`.